# How to set the Path and JAVA-HOME of JDK 1.5 when we are already using JDK 1.6?

Tags: java

I'm using JDK 1.6 at the moment, but I need to use JDK 1.5 now. I have installed the JDK 1.5. I really don't have an idea to set the path. I tried by setting this in the Environment variables:

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0
PATH = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0\bin
```

But still when I check the version in the command prompt it says JDK 1.6.

How do I change it?

Comment: did you close the command prompt and open a new one?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm using JDK 1.6 at the moment, but I need to use JDK 1.5 now.

No, you don't.  Use the [cross-compilation options](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#crosscomp-options), including and especially the `-bootclasspath` option, and the code generated by the Java 6 compiler should be as compatible with Java 1.5 as if it had been compiled with a 1.5 JDK.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the same window after having edited the path variable, as [Jayan suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718827/how-to-set-the-path-and-java-home-of-jdk-1-5when-we-are-already-using-jdk-1-6/6718916#6718916), try to close the Window DOS windows and open a new one and then check the version.

Answer (score 2):

In command-line windows type:

```
set JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0   **hit enter and then type**
set PATH = %JAVA_HOME%\bin   **hit enter and then type**
set
```

Now you will see a list of system variables. You can find **PATH** and **JAVA_HOME** and their values.

If the above values are correct, as you typed previously in a command prompt, type:

```
javac -version
```

The version will be JDK 1.5.xx, and now you can use *[Set JAVA_HOME variable in Windows](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONF26/Set+JAVA_HOME+variable+in+Windows)* to create system variable in Windows.

This is all OK if you compile your code with JDK 1.5 and running with it. Else check [the post by Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718827/how-to-set-the-path-and-java-home-of-jdk-1-5-when-we-are-already-using-jdk-1-6/6718886#6718886).

Answer (score 0):

You may have to edit PATH variable to have the entries correctly ordered.