# Running testng.xml of TestNG framework in maven pom.xml

Tags: maven

I am new to maven. I'm getting this error when I execute tests:

```
`enter code here`[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
    [INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Nikita.Nayak\workspace\123\target\test-classes
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
      C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\..\lib\tools.jar
    Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
    not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
    In most cases you can change the location of your Java
    installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
    [INFO] 1 error
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 1.156s
    [INFO] Finished at: Wed Sep 17 16:21:59 IST 2014
    [INFO] Final Memory: 6M/15M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project 123: Compilation failure
    [ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
    [ERROR] C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\..\lib\tools.jar
    [ERROR] Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
    [ERROR] not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
    [ERROR] In most cases you can change the location of your Java
    [ERROR] installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
```

Comment: You need to configure to use a JDK instead of a JRE.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is your Java configuration. Check if you have the right JDK's version and try to define the right path for it : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6718916/4065027

Hope it helps